# .Net WCF RIA Services parameterized NameValue method crashing

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I added a RIA Domain Service method to return a simple NameValuePair of two properties from a table (and filtered on a key value).

It compiles fine, but blows up every time without giving a useful error.

What am I missing? *(probably something really obvious)*

### e.g.:

```
    public IQueryable<NameValuePair> GetNameValues(int keyId)
    {
        // NOTE: I can breakpoint here and the correct keyId is passed
        // it blows up on returning from this method
        return from p in this.ObjectContext.NameTable
                where p.KeyId == keyId
                select new NameValuePair(p.NameValue, p.NameType);
    }
```

### Simple *NameValuePair* Code:

```
public class NameValuePair
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public NameValuePair()
    {
    }

    public NameValuePair( string name, string value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

### Update:

I tried returning a query on a static list of NameValuePair objects and that works fine (but is not useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this here and got the error: `base {System.SystemException} = {"Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."}`
So you have to change it to create the object first, then pass the property values:

```
public IQueryable<NameValuePair> GetNameValues(int keyId)
{
    return from p in this.ObjectContext.NameTable
            where p.KeyId == keyId
            select new NameValuePair {Name = p.NameValue, Value = p.NameType};
}
```

Comment: +1: This was actually the problem... I had a second unrelated data bug that was causing a crash even when I changed to this format. Thanks for reinforcing the "*can only have a default constructor*" idea :)